# Windows 8.1 won't connect to a Wi-Fi network at system boot

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a problem with a Windows 8.1 system, it won't automatically connect to my home Wi-Fi network at system start.

I have to go to `Control Panel` > `Network and Internet` > `Network Connections`, then right click on the Wi-Fi device and manually disable and re-enable it, and then it will work.

As you can imagine, this if far from optimal; how can I fix this and make it work without manually doing this?

Comment: Have you made sure your wireless adapter drivers are up to date?

Comment: Yes, they are updated